# Add 3 month to the given date in a loop PHP

Tags: php

Hi i have the following `date = 2015-06-01 00:00:00`
 so i have to add 3  month to this date , so write the following code

```
 $sarting="2015-06-01 00:00:00";
  $date[$i]=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($sarting . "+3 months") );
  And i get the output = 2015-09-01;
```

But now i want to add 3 month again and again for 20 times and i have to store the output to array

so i write the following code

```
 $store_date=array();
  for($i=0;$i<20;$i++){
     $store_date[$i]=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($sarting . "+3 months") );
  }
```

But the thing it's returning `2015-09-01` 20 times . i need like this `2015-09-01, 2015-12-01,2016-06-01` etc .

Please check

Comment: Why not use Carbon? https://carbon.nesbot.com/ ?

Comment: _“But the thing it's returning 2015-09-01 20 times”_ - of course it does, because you are adding 3 months to the same starting date in each loop iteration. You either need to _modify_ $sarting, or you simply make the `+3` part dynamic (like `3*($i+1)` or similar.)

Comment: YES. I forgot . thats true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use PHP's [dateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class' `modify()` method to add +3 months in loop to it.

```
<?php
$dateStamp = "2015-06-01 00:00:00";
$date = new DateTime($dateStamp);
$datesArr = [];
for ($i=1; $i<21 ; $i++) {
 $date->modify('+3 month');
 $datesArr[] = $date->format('Y-m-d h:i:s');
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($datesArr);
echo '</pre>';
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2015-09-01 12:00:00
    [1] => 2015-12-01 12:00:00
    [2] => 2016-03-01 12:00:00
    [3] => 2016-06-01 12:00:00
    [4] => 2016-09-01 12:00:00
    [5] => 2016-12-01 12:00:00
    [6] => 2017-03-01 12:00:00
    [7] => 2017-06-01 12:00:00
    [8] => 2017-09-01 12:00:00
    [9] => 2017-12-01 12:00:00
    [10] => 2018-03-01 12:00:00
    [11] => 2018-06-01 12:00:00
    [12] => 2018-09-01 12:00:00
    [13] => 2018-12-01 12:00:00
    [14] => 2019-03-01 12:00:00
    [15] => 2019-06-01 12:00:00
    [16] => 2019-09-01 12:00:00
    [17] => 2019-12-01 12:00:00
    [18] => 2020-03-01 12:00:00
    [19] => 2020-06-01 12:00:00
)
```

[Working Code:](https://3v4l.org/pk51P)

Comment: Could you please tell how can i get 6 month array from this 3 month $datesArr .

Comment: You mean to say instead of 3 months, it should be 6 months?

Comment: Yes . But from the generated $datesArr

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend using the [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)-class so we can reuse the same instance on each iteration.

```
$sarting    = "2015-06-01 00:00:00";
$store_date = [];

// Create a DateTime-object we can reuse
$date = new DateTime($sarting);

for ($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++) {
    $date->modify('+3 months');
    $store_date[] = $date->format('Y-m-d');
}

print_r($store_date);
```

Since we're resuing the same object, it will keep adding 3 months to it on each iteration. No need for any calculations or anything, making the code clean and readable.

Demo: https://3v4l.org/KZiH9

Comment: @abilasher - That question is off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 4):

You are not changing the value of `$sarting`. Try this:

```
$sarting = "2015-06-01 00:00:00";
$store_date = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++) {
    $sarting = $store_date[$i] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($sarting . "+3 months"));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this check if it helps,

```
$sarting="2015-06-01 00:00:00";

$store_date=array();
  for($i=0;$i<20;$i++){
     $store_date[$i]=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($sarting . "+3 months") );
     $sarting=$store_date[$i];
  }

 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($store_date);
 echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code for Addition or Subtraction for Year/Month/day from date

Addition = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+0 years +3 months +0 days", strtotime($lastdate)));

Subtraction = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+0 years -3 months +0 days", strtotime($lastdate)));

```
$lastdate = "01-12-2015"; //actual date

$after_3_month = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+0 years +3 months +0 days", strtotime($lastdate))); // adding 3 month on the actual date

echo $after_3_month; //3 month added with actual date
```